# Simple Regex - logic help needed to match a string but not as character class

Tags: php, regex

I have the following sample template code.

```
{# @T('core.layout:Logged in as {0} {1}', @user('firstname'), @user('lastname')) #} {# VAR_TEST #}
```

And the following regex used to parse for the tags

```
/{# (\@)?(([A-Z][^#}]+)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)?\(([^#}]*)\))) #}/
```

However it only matches the last tag because of the close curly braces (}) in the first tag. I'm no expert in regex and thus the problem. I'm attempting to limit the matching by stopping the tags matching anything after the tag close #} by using the every character except #} pattern, ie [^#}]. However this is matching individual characters and not the #} string as a whole.

How to you write a regex to match everything but a string but not in character class mode?

Fyi, the regex flavour is PHP and preg_match.

---

Edit 1;

So I need to match

```
{# @T('core.layout:Logged in as {0} {1}', @user('firstname'), @user('lastname')) #}
```

and

```
{# VAR_TEST #}
```

with the same regex. however the first test match indicates a very complicated tag which is broken down with further regexes at a later point.

Comment: Sorry, i read your Question Twice, but I don't get what exactly it is you want to catch with your regex? Every Non-String Charachter? that would simply be preg_match_all('#[^\w]#',$subject,$matches);

Comment: Not really, in theory it would however the various parts of the syntax denote various things. for example if @ is present then the tag is dynamic and never compiled into the template and always processed. That said I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion: `(?!#})`.

But personally I would write the PCRE as: `/{#.*?#}/` That's way more straightforward ;)

Comment: The trouble doing /{#.*?#}/ is that I would then have to break down every subsequent matched tag to get the tag parts out. But I suppose if this is a simpler regex it would be more optimal to run this and then parse out the tag data for each matched tag?

Comment: accepted as answer for suggesting the use of /{#.*?#}/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?:(?!#\}).)*
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:      # match the following:
 (?!#\}) # assert that it's impossible to match #} here (but don't actually match it)
 .       # match any character
)*       # zero or more times
```

Comment: This does work also. Thanks very much for the regex comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `[^#}]*` with `([^#]|#[^}])*`.